# How get Mercurial changes when I've already used hg clone?

Tags: mercurial

Worked on my repo from work, and hg pushed the changes. Now in my home computer, how do I get the changes I saved from work considering I've already hg cloned the repo about two weeks ago but haven't updated since?

I need something like a hg getchanges or something?

http://bitbucket.org/sergiotapia/sharpdic

Comment: Have you read http://hginit.com/?

Comment: Yeah read it about a month ago. Great site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$ hg pull     # copy changesets from remote default path to local repo
$ hg update   # update working directory

$ hg pull -u  # above two commands in one step
```

The default path is the 'default' key in the paths section of .hg/hgrc in your repo; see `hg help paths` for more.  Authorization info (required to push to bitbucket) is either stored in that URL (http://user:pass@...) or the [auth](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#auth) section of .hg/hgrc or ~/.hgrc.

Answer (score 8):

`hg pull` followed by `hg update` should do the trick.

Comment: Jeffrey is correct, but let me elaborate. You say you've pushed from work. That means that wherever you've pushed to has those changes. 

By default, `push` sends changes to wherever you did the `clone` from and `pull` takes changes from wherever you did the `clone` from.

If work is a clone of home, then you only need to do an `hg update` from home, no pull necessary because you already pushed it to there. If home is a clone of work, then you didn't need to `push` anything from work, just `pull` when you get home. :)